# How to control Google Navigation Bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, uinavigationbar, chat, navigationbar

I am using Google_Nav_Bar and i didn't know how to put code on the page should i create a new file for everypage? and how to control it?

google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6  here is my code in homepage   [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIVEa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please post code using `Code Sample` next time. I've never used `Google_Nav_Bar` but it looks like you're missing a `setState` call.

```
selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTabChange: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in your mind, nav bar is just separate widget (an independence thing). You should change "body" widget when user click on each items in that navbar.